# парсинг где ошибка не записывает в бд

Tags: php

```
<?php
$host='localhost'; // имя хоста (уточняется у провайдера)
$user='ggefesq4_mysite'; // заданное вами имя пользователя, либо определенное провайдером
$pswd='www045'; // заданный вами пароль
$database='ggefesq4_mysite'; // имя базы данных, которую вы должны создать

$rssSQL = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");

$xml_file = "http://rss.medicalnewstoday.com/it-internet-e-mail.xml";


    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);




foreach ($sxml->channel->item as $item){

    $title = $item->title;
    $date= $item->pubDate;
    $link = $item->link;
    $description = $item->description;
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO it (id,title, pubdate, 
               link,description) VALUES(0,'.$title.','.$date.', '.$link.','.$description.')");


    $retval = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$retval ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $strtemp = "<p><a href=\"$item->link\">"."$item->title</a> <span class=\"time\" style=\"font-size:11px;color:#555;\">".date("d.m.Y",strtotime($item->pubDate))."</span></p>\n";
    echo $strtemp;
}




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас написана ерунда в запросе. Ваш вариант:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `it` (`id`, `title`, `pubdate`, `link`, `description`) VALUES (0, $title, $date, $link, $description)");
```

Смотрите, если Вы пишете выражение в двойных кавычках, то PHP сам попытается подставить переменные. Если в одинарных то так:

```
$sql = ('INSERT INTO `it` (`id`, `title`, `pubdate`, `link`, `description`) VALUES (0, '.$title.', '.$date.', '.$link.', '.$description.')');
```

А Вы написали что-то среднее. Также переменные не обезательно переопределять:

```
$title = $item->title;
$date= $item->pubDate;
$link = $item->link;
$description = $item->description;
```

```
$sql = ('INSERT INTO `it` (`id`, `title`, `pubdate`, `link`, `description`) VALUES (0, '.$item->title.', '.$item->pubDate.', '.$item->link.', '.$item->description.')');
```